# GitHub API secret encryption with libsodium in Node.js: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: bad public key size

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, encryption, libsodium

I want to set a repository secret via the GitHub REST API. I use the example from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#example-encrypting-a-secret-using-nodejs):

```
const sodium = require('tweetsodium');

const key = "base64-encoded-public-key";
const value = "plain-text-secret";

// Convert the message and key to Uint8Array's (Buffer implements that interface)
const messageBytes = Buffer.from(value);
const keyBytes = Buffer.from(key, 'base64');

// Encrypt using LibSodium.
const encryptedBytes = sodium.seal(messageBytes, keyBytes);

// Base64 the encrypted secret
const encrypted = Buffer.from(encryptedBytes).toString('base64');

console.log(encrypted);
```

I receive this error:

```
(node:6008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: bad public key size
    at checkBoxLengths (C:\Users\User\probot\node_modules\tweetnacl\nacl-fast.js:2158:54)
    at Function.nacl.box.before (C:\Users\User\probot\node_modules\tweetnacl\nacl-fast.js:2231:3)
    at Object.nacl.box (C:\Users\User\probot\node_modules\tweetnacl\nacl-fast.js:2225:20)
    at Object.tweetSodium.seal (C:\Users\User\probot\node_modules\tweetsodium\dist\index.umd.js:53:33)
    at createSecret (C:\Users\User\probot\src\service\secret.js:55:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\probot\src\service\secret.js:73:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
(node:6008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6008) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Problem**: How do I correctly encrypt and decrypt the secret so i can use it in my API?

**Solution**: @Topaco mentioned that you need to use a base64 encoded key such as `2Sg8iYjAxxmI2LvUXpJjkYrMxURPc8r+dB7TJyvvcCU=`. This solves the error descibed above.

**EDIT**

I will use different secrets in different repositories. Should I generate a new base64 encoded key for each repo?

Comment: have you checked this https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetsodium

Comment: Yes but I am still at a loss in how to use that for the GitHub API.

Comment: According to the error message it looks like you just executed the posted code. You must apply a valid Base64 encoded key, e.g. `2Sg8iYjAxxmI2LvUXpJjkYrMxURPc8r+dB7TJyvvcCU=` (see the linked documentation).

Comment: What base64 encoded key am I supposed to use? Can I just use any? Do I have to use one of the keys I get from GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example code was not quite clear what the `key` actually is and where you get it. You need the "repository public key" that you get from the [`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/codespaces/secrets/public-key`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/codespaces/repository-secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-repository-public-key) endpoint.

Use the repository public key together with the value from your new secret:

```
const key = "base64-encoded-public-key"; // this is the repository public key you need to fetch from GitHub
const value = "plain-text-secret"; // the secret value
```

Then you can [create or update](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/codespaces/repository-secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-a-repository-secret) your key:

```
  const res = await octokit.actions.createOrUpdateRepoSecret({
    owner: "GITHUBUSER",  
    repo: "GITHUB_REPO", 
    secret_name: "KEY_NAME", 
    encrypted_value: encrypted,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that I used.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const sodium = require('tweetsodium');
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/core");

// Create a personal access token at https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo
const octokit = new Octokit({ auth: process.env.GH_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN });

module.exports = async () => {
  const encryptionKey = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  const publicKeyResponse = await octokit.request('GET /repos/<USERNAME>/<REPO>/actions/secrets/public-key');
  const publicKey = publicKeyResponse.data.key;
  const publicKeyId = publicKeyResponse.data.key_id;

  // Convert the message and key to Uint8Array's (Buffer implements that interface)
  const messageBytes = Buffer.from(encryptionKey);
  const keyBytes = Buffer.from(publicKey, 'base64');

  // Encrypt using LibSodium.
  const encryptedBytes = sodium.seal(messageBytes, keyBytes);

  // Base64 the encrypted secret
  const encryptedEncryptionKey = Buffer.from(encryptedBytes).toString('base64');

  await octokit.request('PUT /repos/<USERNAME>/<REPO>/actions/secrets/ENCRYPTION_KEY', {
    owner: '<USERNAME>',
    repo: '<REPO>',
    secret_name: 'ENCRYPTION_KEY',
    key_id: publicKeyId,
    encrypted_value: encryptedEncryptionKey,
  });

  return encryptionKey;
};
```

Comment: This managed to solve it for. The part I was missing was fetching the public key and public ID from the repo. I thought I had to create those values but turns out they exist for each repo.